magento 2.4.1 unable to upload supported file types
I've been trying to upload images, including .jpeg, .jpg, .png, and .gif formats, but I keep encountering an issue where the files won't upload. The error message I receive is:

'F71302_wl.jpg was not uploaded. Unsupported image format.'

It doesn't seem to matter what the file size is, as there are no noticeable differences between the images that does work and those that don't. Since I am an intern with limited options, I’m not sure what else to try at this point

Do you mean Magento instead of Magneto?

yeah i did sorry
